# Response variable on 0-100 scale, but missing a single value -- Bayesian model

Tags: r, bayesian, model

I am constructing a bayesian model in brms. I have a response variable that is on a 0-100 scale, however, all values of 50 have been removed. Additionally, there are an outsized proportion of 0's and 100's. To deal with the 0's and 100's, I am using the `zero_one_inflated_beta()` family. However, how can I tell the model that it should not expect to see any values of 50?
Thank you.

Values of 50 were removed because the data collection instrument was flawed. The slider had a default value of 50 and we ended up with a ridiculous amount of 50 ratings. This gives us reason to believe many participants may have skipped through the rating screen in order to finish the exercise. I am posting the histograms with and without 50 removed. Note that there are two ratings per measurement occasion, labeled "pre" and "post". In the dataset with 50s removed there are 2.11% zeros and 11.80% hundreds. In the dataset without 50s removed there are 1.64% zeros and 9.15% hundreds.
[image: histogram without 50]
[image: histogram with 50]

Comment: Why were the values of 50 removed? And could you post a histogram of your data? What percent are at 0 and 100, respectively?

Comment: Thank you for your questions. I have responded in the body of the post. Please let me know if I can clarify anything else.